# Unable to configure terraform dynamic block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create aws_workspace_workspaces by passing the values to dynamic block but its not picking up the values from there. The main aim is to automatically distributes the value to the resource. it shows this error

`on modules/aws_workspace/main.tf line 4, in resource "aws_workspaces_workspace" "example": │    4:     dynamic "aws_workspace" { │  │ Blocks of type "aws_workspace" are not expected here.`

dev.tfvars

```
aws_workspace={    
  user_name    = "john.doe"
  root_volume_encryption_enabled = true
  user_volume_encryption_enabled = true
  volume_encryption_key          = "alias/aws/workspaces"

  workspace_properties = {
    compute_type_name                         = "VALUE"
    user_volume_size_gib                      = 10
    root_volume_size_gib                      = 80
    running_mode                              = "AUTO_STOP"
    running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes = 60
  }
}
tags = {
    Department = "IT"
}
```

```
resource "aws_workspaces_workspace" "example" {
    directory_id = var.directory_id
    bundle_id    = var.bundle_id
    dynamic "aws_workspace" {
        for_each = var.aws_workspace
        content {
            user_name    = aws_workspace.value.user_name

            root_volume_encryption_enabled = aws_workspace.value.root_volume_encryption_enabled
            user_volume_encryption_enabled = aws_workspace.value.user_volume_encryption_enabled
            volume_encryption_key          = aws_workspace.value.volume_encryption_key

            workspace_properties {
                compute_type_name                         = aws_workspace.value.compute_type_name
                user_volume_size_gib                      = aws_workspace.value.user_volume_size_gib
                root_volume_size_gib                      = aws_workspace.value.root_volume_size_gib
                running_mode                              = aws_workspace.value.running_mode
                running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes = aws_workspace.value.running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes
            }
        }
    }
  tags = {
    Department = "IT"
  }
}
```

So If I pass the value to of another user it creates it as well, this is the basic aim that I am trying to achieve

```
module "my_workspaces" {
    source = "./modules/workspaces"

    hosts = {
        "user1" = {
            "user_name"                                 = "user1.last1",
            "compute_type_name"                         = var.compute_type_name
            "user_volume_size_gib"                      = var.user_volume_size_gib,
            "root_volume_size_gib"                      = var.root_volume_size_gib,
            "running_mode"                              = var.running_mode,
            "running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes" = var.auto_stop_timeout_min
        },
        "user2" = {
            "user_name"                                 = "user2.last2",
            "compute_type_name"                         = var.compute_type_name
            "user_volume_size_gib"                      = var.user_volume_size_gib,
            "root_volume_size_gib"                      = var.root_volume_size_gib,
            "running_mode"                              = var.running_mode,
            "running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes" = var.auto_stop_timeout_min
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such block as `aws_workspace` in `aws_workspaces_workspace`. What do you want to do? maybe you are using wrong resource?

Comment: I am trying to loop over the variable and assigns the value to the aws_workspace, I have updated the question with what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So If I pass the value to of another user it creates it as well, this is the basic aim that i am trying to achieve. Just passing the values from dev.tfvars would create the new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such block as aws_workspace in aws_workspaces_workspace. You should use `for_each` directly:

```
resource "aws_workspaces_workspace" "example" {
    directory_id = var.directory_id
    bundle_id    = var.bundle_id

    for_each = var.aws_workspace

    user_name    = each.value.user_name

    root_volume_encryption_enabled = each.value.root_volume_encryption_enabled
    user_volume_encryption_enabled = each.value.user_volume_encryption_enabled
    volume_encryption_key          = each.value.volume_encryption_key

    workspace_properties {
        compute_type_name                         = each.value.compute_type_name
        user_volume_size_gib                      = each.value.user_volume_size_gib
        root_volume_size_gib                      = each.value.root_volume_size_gib
        running_mode                              = each.value.running_mode
        running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes = each.value.running_mode_auto_stop_timeout_in_minutes
    }


  tags = {
    Department = "IT"
  }
}
```